# Refused to set unsafe header "Connection" for chrome browser core.ashx

Tags: ajax, google-chrome

I am implementing a functionality where am referring core.ashx file which works for IE but it gives an error 'Refused to set unsafe header "Connection"' in google chrome.

below are the console log error details.

> ajaxpro\core.ashx
>
> if(!MS.Browser.isIE) {
>               this.xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");       // Mozilla Bug #246651

I followed some articles which are highlighting about security concerns related chrome browser and hence "xmlHttp.setRequestHeader" will not run in chrome browser.

Any help is appreciated.

-Shrivallabh Davalbhakt